# Passar valor de uma variavél em JS para uma variavél em PHP, para então executar determinada ação de acordo com o valor da variavel

Tags: php, javascript

O sistema esta todo estruturado em php, estou querendo utilizar a funcionalidade confirm() do Js, 
para confirmar se o usuario realmente deseja remover um registro do banco de dados, quando retornar "true" ele remove do BD, 
e quando retornar "false" não remove.  o problema acontece quando tento transferir o valor da variavel do Js para uma variavel em PHP.
o valor recebido pela variavel php sempre é igual a "1" independente se o usuario clicou em "ok" ou "cancel",
tendo em vista que o resultado é sempre o mesmo dificulta bastante a tomada de decisão de acordo com a escolha do usuario. 
Tenho consciencia que as duas linguages são para finalidades diferentes, uma para rodar no servidor(php), 
e outra no navegador(JS). e creio que seja por esse fato que esteja ocorrendo este "erro". tenho muito pouco conhecimento em Js.

CODIGO:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['del'])){
        $del=$_GET['del'];
        $name_brinquedo_GET=$_GET['brinquedo'];

        print "
        <script>var info=window.confirm('Tem certeza que deseja REMOVER permanentemente o cadastro de $name_brinquedo_GET');</script>";
        $recebeJs=print "<script>document.write(info);</script>";

        if($recebeJs){
            //Apagando registros do bd
            $drop= new Registro_brinquedo();
            $drop->DropRegistros($del); 
        }else{
            unset($_GET['del']);
            unset($_GET['brinquedo']);
        }

    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

PHP trabalha do lado do servidor, não é possível ler algo do cliente em "tempo de execução", não que eu saiba, uma resposta pra isso seria você fazer o seguinte:

cria uma pagina que recebe um valor get por exemplo, pagina.php?del=yes
e no php fazer o código se o del for verdadeiro

e no javascript você faria um if com o confirm
se sim abre essa pagina em segundo plano com o window.open ou similar passando o parâmetro del verdadeiro, se não passaria o parâmetro del como falso

assim:

pagina de auxilio

```
if($_GET['deletar'] == true) {
   $drop= new Registro_brinquedo();
   $drop->DropRegistros($del);
}
```

e na pagina ficaria

```js
if(confirm('Tem certeza que deseja REMOVER permanentemente o cadastro de' + variavel_nome_do_brinquedo + '?')) {
    window.open('auxilio.php?deletar=true','_blank')
}
```